# how to control painting order for sibling windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have 2 child windows (black RECT, and White RECT) and a button, as the image
[image]

this windows were created in the order: (the button > the white > the black), and i didn't change the Z-Order as :

```
   //the Button Creation Code Is ommited 
    White = CreateWindowEx(0,ctrFace,"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
        rc.left-10,  rc.top-10, rc.right-rc.left,  rc.bottom-rc.top,   GetParent(hwnd),0,Hinstance,0);
    Black = CreateWindowEx(0,ctrUpDownNodes,"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
        rc.left-20,  rc.top-20, rc.right-rc.left,  rc.bottom-rc.top,   GetParent(hwnd),0,Hinstance,0);

    //SetWindowPos(White ,HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Case 2 : Now when I set the white child on the top of z order by uncommenting the last `SetWindowPos` call I get this

[image]

the code after uncommenting the last call to put the white child on the top of z order is as :

```
    White = CreateWindowEx(0,ctrFace,"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
        rc.left-10,  rc.top-10, rc.right-rc.left,  rc.bottom-rc.top,   GetParent(hwnd),0,Hinstance,0);
    Black = CreateWindowEx(0,ctrUpDownNodes,"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
        rc.left-20,  rc.top-20, rc.right-rc.left,  rc.bottom-rc.top,   GetParent(hwnd),0,Hinstance,0);
    SetWindowPos(White ,HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

**What I want:**

- I want The White child to block any mouse message from getting to it's siblings whenever the mouse is over the white child ( I get this done by butting the white child `HWND_TOP`)
- and I want the white child to be painted over the other siblings (the button, and the black child) .

**The Problem:**

Whenever I call `SetWindowPos` with  `HWND_TOP` to make the window block the messages from other windows, The Window ALWAYS Painted underneath the other windows , but it blocks the messages from it's siblings correctly as I want though.

**How Can I but the white on top of z order to take all mouse messages and get it painted on top of them too ?**

*Note: I can't Use `SW_CLIPSIBLINGS` for the black and button because I want them to be painted also but get covered by the white, and this style will prevent the button and the black clipped areas from being painted at all.*

**Note 2 : `HWND_TOP` make the window draw at the very buttom of it's siblings
and `HWND_BUTTOM` makes the window draw at the very top of it's siblings !!! why?**

EDIT: reacting to comments this is the tool that I want to make

[image]

Comment: "because I want them to be painted also but get covered by the white, and this style will prevent the button and the black clipped areas from being painted at all" doesn't make sense. What's the point of painting them if you're only going to paint over them?

Comment: @JonathanPotter because I'm trying to build a GUI designer that generate codes in C language  and I need a tool to control other controls like buttons, listboxes, etc. - and I need this tool to cover the buttons and other child windows and take the mouse messages and to be hollow at the same time to let me see the control under neath it... I'm attaching an image for it

Comment: In that case I would use `DrawThemeBackground` etc to render my own simulated button objects rather than try to cover up real buttons with some funky transparent-but-not sibling window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I will try this approach , thank you very much